# Current regulation compensation SG3524 and right place to place sense resistor

Tags: current, switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator, compensation

What is the right place to place current sense resistor? As in picture we get traingular wave n position 1, sine wave with highest amplitude on pos 2, smaller sine wave on pos 3 and nearly flat line but still there is sine wave on pos 4. There is DC Offset ofcourse and since its all symetrticaly moving around constant value its mean value is "same" for all positions.
I am able to stabilise control voltage part, but on current regulation, it just wont get stable.I guess pos 4 is the right one. Also worth mentioning SG3524 has transconductance error amplifiers. I am gonna use TL072 instead and its output connect to COMP pin. Thanks
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) so that the loop can be closed on current (average current mode control).  Then add another error amp to regulate voltage.

Comment: this video helps me to understand what is acm control about https://www.coursera.org/lecture/current-modecontrol/introduction-to-average-current-mode-control-tL0cn